# AWS EMR format datanode periodically

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

I am using EMR & running a spark streaming job with yarn as resource manager and Hadoop 2.7.3-amzn-0,

I want clean periodic datanode files like /mnt/hdfs/current/BP-2030300665-192.168.0.1-1495611838265/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir230/blk_1073800835
& blk_1073800835_60012.meta

Its increase my storage and facing disk storage full issue.

Is there any way to achieve the same or any impact on my cluster if i delete the same?